# Loop through two data frames and concatenate contents to string

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops, string-concatenation

I am trying to create a large list of file URLs by concatenating various pieces together. (Say, ~40 file URLs which represent multiple data types for each of the 50 states.) Eventually, I will download and then unzip/unrar these files. (I have working code for that portion of it.)

I'm very much an R noob, so please bear with me, here.

I have a set of data frames:

**states** - list of 50 state abbreviations

**partial_url** - a partial URL for the 50 states

**url_parts** - a list of each of the remaining URL
   pieces (5 file types to download)

**year**

**filetype**

I need a URL that looks like this:
http://partial_url/state_urlpart_2017_file.csv.gz

I was able to build the **partial_url** data frame with the following:

```
for (i in seq_along(states)) {
  url_part1 <- as.data.frame(paste0(url,states[[i]],"/",dir,"/"))

}
```

I was hoping that some kind of nested loop might work to do the rest, like so:

```
for (i in 1:partial_url){
  for (j in 1:url_parts){
    for(k in 1:states){
      url_part2 <- as.data.frame(paste0(partial_url[[i]],"/",url_parts[[j]],states[[k]],year,filetype))
    }}}
```

Can anyone suggest how to proceed with the final step?

Comment: It helps to provide example data so we know what you are actually working with. For example, you say you have 5 data frames but then describe some as lists - these are words that have specific meanings in R.

Comment: Are all dataframes have same numbers of rows? You `for-loop` suggest those dataframes got same number of rows and those are matching `row number` for same record.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding all OP needs can be handled by `paste0` function itself. The `paste0` works as vectorise format. Hence, the `for-loop` shown by OP is not needed. The data used in my example is stored in `vector` format but it can be represented by a column of `data.frame`.

For example:

```
states <- c("Alabama", "Colorado", "Georgia")
partial_url <- c("URL_1", "URL_2", "URL_3")
url_parts <- c("PART_1", "PART_2", "PART_3")
year <- 2017
fileType <- "xls"

#Now use paste0 will list out all the URLS
paste0(partial_url,"/",url_parts,states,year,fileType)

#[1] "URL_1/PART_1Alabama2017xls"  "URL_2/PART_2Colorado2017xls"
#[3] "URL_3/PART_3Georgia2017xls"
```

EDIT: multiple fileType based on feedback from @Onyambu
We can use `rep(fileType, each = length(states))` to support multiple files. 
The solution will look like.

```
fileType <- c("xls", "doc")

paste0(partial_url,"/",url_parts,states,year,rep(fileType,each = length(states)))
[1] "URL_1/PART_1Alabama2017xls"  "URL_2/PART_2Colorado2017xls" "URL_3/PART_3Georgia2017xls" 
[4] "URL_1/PART_1Alabama2017doc"  "URL_2/PART_2Colorado2017doc" "URL_3/PART_3Georgia2017doc"
```

Comment: this does not solve the question asked. look at the for-loop again. you should have 27 urls from your example

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks for pointing it out. We can use `rep` with `each` to generate URLs for multiple type. I have updated my answer for the same.

Comment: Are those 27?. They seem to be 9.. you should have 27 files. Yes you are right you can use rec or outer etc

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks. there are only 6 files. I think OP needs to clarify few things. IMO, `states` and `partial_url` have 1-1 relationship. `url_parts` can be multiple which associate with each of `states` or 1-1 relation. OP needs to specify. My answer provides enough details which suggest OP needs can be met. I can modify my answer once I hear from OP.

Comment: I se what you mean. Sorry. I thought the forloop was correct. But maybe it# not

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution with some simple example data. The approach is to use `complete` to give yourself a data frame with all possible combinations of your variables. This works because if you make each variable a factor, `complete` will include all possible factor levels even if they don't appear. This makes it easy to combine your five url parts even though they appear to have different `nrow` (e.g. 50 states but only 5 file types). `unite` allows you to join together columns as strings, so we call it three times to include the right separators, and then finally add the `http://` with `mutate`.

Re: your `for` loop, I find it hard to work through nested `for` loop logic in the first place. But at least two issues as written include that you have `1:partial_url` instead of `1:length(partial_url)` and similar, and you are simply overwriting the same object with every pass of the loop. I prefer to avoid loops unless it's a problem where they're absolutely necessary.

```r
library(tidyverse)
states <- tibble(state = c("AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "NY"))
partial_url <- tibble(part = c("part1", "part2"))
url_parts <- tibble(urlpart = c("urlpart1", "urlpart2"))
year <- tibble(year = 2007:2010)
filetype <- tibble(filetype = c("csv", "txt", "tar"))

urls <- bind_cols(
  states = states[[1]] %>% factor() %>% head(2),
  partial_url = partial_url[[1]] %>% factor() %>% head(2),
  url_parts = url_parts[[1]] %>% factor() %>% head(2),
  year = year[[1]] %>% factor() %>% head(2),
  filetype = filetype[[1]] %>% factor() %>% head(2)
  ) %>%
  complete(states, partial_url, url_parts, year, filetype) %>%
  unite("middle", states, url_parts, year, sep = "_") %>%
  unite("end", middle, filetype, sep = ".") %>%
  unite("url", partial_url, end, sep = "/") %>%
  mutate(url = str_c("http://", url))
print(urls)
# A tibble: 160 x 1
   url                              
   <chr>                            
 1 http://part1/AK_urlpart1_2007.csv
 2 http://part1/AK_urlpart1_2007.txt
 3 http://part1/AK_urlpart1_2008.csv
 4 http://part1/AK_urlpart1_2008.txt
 5 http://part1/AK_urlpart1_2009.csv
 6 http://part1/AK_urlpart1_2009.txt
 7 http://part1/AK_urlpart1_2010.csv
 8 http://part1/AK_urlpart1_2010.txt
 9 http://part1/AK_urlpart2_2007.csv
10 http://part1/AK_urlpart2_2007.txt
# ... with 150 more rows
```

Created on 2018-02-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).